# Looping through XML nodes and comparing the text of its elements in Python

Tags: python, xml, loops, nodes, element

I'm dealing with a XML file of which a part of it is shown below:

```
<tblSampleParts>
    <AnID>1</AnID>
    <JrID>11</JrID>
</tblSampleParts>
<tblSampleParts>
    <AnID>2</AnID>
    <JrID>16</JrID>
</tblSampleParts>
<tblSampleParts>
    <AnID>2</AnID>
    <JrID>28</JrID>
</tblSampleParts>
<tblSampleParts>
    <AnID>2</AnID>
    <JrID>29</JrID>
<tblSampleParts>
    <AnID>3</AnID>
    <JrID>5</JrID>
</tblSampleParts>
<tblSampleParts>
    <AnID>4</AnID>
    <JrID>22</JrID>
</tblSampleParts>
<tblSampleParts>
    <AnID>5</AnID>
    <JrID>12</JrID>
</tblSampleParts>
<tblSampleParts>
    <AnID>5</AnID>
    <JrID>18</JrID>
<tblSampleParts>
    <AnID>6</AnID>
    <JrID>6</JrID>
</tblSampleParts>
```

What I want to do is loop through the nodes and compare the values of the "AnID" element. If the value of an "AnID " is shown more than once, then I want to print the text of the AnID's and the corresponding JrID's. So what I wish to be printed when looking at the attached code is:

```
    <AnID>2</AnID>
    <JrID>16</JrID>

    <AnID>2</AnID>
    <JrID>28</JrID>

    <AnID>2</AnID>
    <JrID>29</JrID>

    <AnID>5</AnID>
    <JrID>12</JrID>

    <AnID>5</AnID>
    <JrID>18</JrID>
```

I've tried it myself and used the int() function to convert the text to an integer and try and loop trough all the nodes, but I errors like 'string indices must be integers'.

Currently I'm using the following code to collect and print the values of the AnID's and JrID's:

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml import objectify
path='0458510148.xml'
parsed=objectify.parse(open(path))
root=parsed.getroot()


data=[]
skip_fields=['tblProjects','tblMeasurementPoints']

for elt in root.tblSampleParts:
    el_data={}
    for child in elt.getchildren():
        el_data[child.tag]=child.pyval
    data.append(el_data)


perf=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(perf)
```

This gives the following outcome:

```
    AnID  JrID
0      1    11
1      2    16
2      2    28
3      3     5
4      4    22
5      5    12
6      6     6
7      7     1
8      8    17
9      9    18
10    10    10
11    10    13
12    10    24
13    11     2
14    11     8
15    11    14
16    11    25
17    12    10
18    13    13
19    14    24
```

But I don't know how to only print the AnID's (with their corresponding JrID's) whose number comes up more than once.

Comment: Please provide the code you have been using that show the errors you have stated above. That way, we have a starting point to improve on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I gave it a shot:

```py
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample_data = """
<xml>
    <tblSampleParts>
        <AnID>1</AnID>
        <JrID>11</JrID>
    </tblSampleParts>
    <tblSampleParts>
        <AnID>2</AnID>
        <JrID>16</JrID>
    </tblSampleParts>
    <tblSampleParts>
        <AnID>2</AnID>
        <JrID>28</JrID>
    </tblSampleParts>
    <tblSampleParts>
        <AnID>2</AnID>
        <JrID>29</JrID>
    <tblSampleParts>
        <AnID>3</AnID>
        <JrID>5</JrID>
    </tblSampleParts>
    <tblSampleParts>
        <AnID>4</AnID>
        <JrID>22</JrID>
    </tblSampleParts>
    <tblSampleParts>
        <AnID>5</AnID>
        <JrID>12</JrID>
    </tblSampleParts>
    <tblSampleParts>
        <AnID>5</AnID>
        <JrID>18</JrID>
    <tblSampleParts>
        <AnID>6</AnID>
        <JrID>6</JrID>
    </tblSampleParts>
</xml>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(sample_data, 'xml')

parts = soup.find_all('tblSampleParts')

AnIDs = []
JrIDs = []
for p in parts:
    an = p.AnID.text
    AnIDs.append(an)
    jr = p.JrID.text
    JrIDs.append(jr)

for i, a in enumerate(AnIDs):
    if AnIDs.count(a) > 1:
        print(f'<AnID>{a}</AnID>\n<JrID>{JrIDs[i]}</JrID>')
```

This prints

```sh
<AnID>2</AnID>
<JrID>16</JrID>
<AnID>2</AnID>
<JrID>28</JrID>
<AnID>2</AnID>
<JrID>29</JrID>
<AnID>5</AnID>
<JrID>12</JrID>
<AnID>5</AnID>
<JrID>18</JrID>
```

I'm guessing that should be what you wanted, right?

### Update:

BeautifulSoup doesn't provide a function to read files/web pages directly.

If you have the data locally, as a file `data.xml`, you can do the following (this assumes the file is in the same folder as the script - use relative paths):

```py
with open('data.xml', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'xml')
```

If you want to use online data, do the following:

```py
import requests

url = "http://some.url.com/data.xml"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'xml')
```

(should roughly work, haven't tried it though, so you may have to tweak it here and there)

Comment: Currently you paste the markup in the code itself named as `sample_data`. In what way would you import a XML file so that `soup = BeautifulSoup(XXXX, 'xml')
` would still work? So importing a file and then computing your code and getting the same outcome as you've right now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is much reason to convert it to integer, you can compare the string value just as well.

You could try the following:

- create a dictionary
- loop over each `<tblSampleParts>`

  - use the string in `<AnID>` as `k` and the string of `<JrID>` as `v`
  - if the key is not in the dict, add the key `k` and a list `[v]` as value to the dict
  - if the key is in the dict, append `v` to the list
- loop over each key-value-pair in the dict

  - if the list in the value contains only one element, skip it
  - if the list contains more elements, that's one of the cases you're looking for.

I'm sure, there are better, more efficient and more pythonic ways to do it. But this should work, at least.

In any case, for this solution, you can use the string `"5"` just as well as the integer `5` as a key.
However, if you insist on converting the strings to integers, and keep getting errors, you may want to look into what the strings are, that cause these errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat convoluted, but can be done using xpath:

```
from lxml import etree

ids = """<root>[your xml above[</root>""" #note: the xml in the question is not well formed; it needs to be wrapped in a root element

uniq_anids = {id for id in doc.xpath('//AnID/text()')}
targets = [u_a for u_a in uniq_anids if doc.xpath(f'count(//AnID[text()="{u_a}"])')>1]
for target in targets:
    for tsp in doc.xpath(f'//tblSampleParts[./AnID[text()="{target}"]]/*'):
        print(etree.tostring(tsp).decode())
```

The output should be the one indicated in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I used your code adding  `parsed=objectify.parse(open('filename.xml'))`and replacing `doc` with `parsed`, but I didnt get the correct result. I got all the AnID's and corresponding JrID's as output, but then mixed up. (in the original xml file it starts with `AnID 1` follow by `AnID 2` etc.)

Comment: @Murcie I can only work with the information in your question and assume it represents the actual xml.